# Chevron / drop down to activate keypad

Tags: gui-design, dropdown, keypad

I want users to understand how to adjust the quantity of products.

We can't include a dropdown and allow users to input text. So for now, we're removing the dropdown and allowing text input only.

My question is, how do users know that this box can be edited or will users generally understand that by tapping the gold box, they can edit the quantity with their native device keypad?

See the screenshots attached.

Default with chevron. On tap, the chevron disappears and number is highlighted to show it can be edited, keypad appears.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Answer (score 2):

When adding things to cart, usually the input is a number. Hence using a - (minus) and + (plus) helps in getting what the user wants.

A few advantages:

- We can control the max (and min) values that the user can add,
  based on logic
- We will not get stray/erroneous input values
- More affordance that this is an editable field
- We can still have the whole page in view since there is no
  numpad required

[image: Example of a cart adder]